# Create Page Layouts in SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, page-layout, sharepoint-designer

Need to create `Page Layout` with multiple `tr`s and three columns layout in my SP 2010 site collection.

I have a requirement to create a home page with the above and add an image and  description of the site and add few links to the `document libraries` or `SPLists`.

Does the existing page layouts be sufficient for my requirement?
Should I create a page layouts using `SPDesigner` ?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can Create the layout with SharePoint Designar if you hace to do just this (add some webpart zones forma the imagen, descripción and other possibly webpart). In addition, configure the site imagen and description by hand and the other data, links, etc., too.

If you expect to get more work, think about a Visual Studio development to grow up as your requirements do.

Answer (score 2):

Using SharePoint Designer you can create multiple zones in a page layout.

Just Create a Page with any layout.

Create an HTML Prototype like below:

```
<table id="masterTable">
   <tr><td> Your 1st new webpart zone here </td></tr>
   <tr><td> Your 2nd new webpart zone here </td></tr>
   <tr><td> Your 3rd new webpart zone here </td></tr>
</table>
```

Copy layouts fro the page you created and put them in the above **`<td>`** also
make sure you keep distinct Title and ID for the zones. Paste this table in your above custom page.

To add an image and description of the site and add few links to the document libraries or SPLists you have multiple webparts already available if anything remaining you can achieve in CEWB (Content Editor WebPart).

You can apply branding also as you want. Add reference to your css file and js file.